# IIS default page doesn't work

Tags: iis, iis-10

I think I must have changed something to IIS default website settings. Now I cannot even browse IIS default website. Even if I create new website, when I browse, it always go to http://localhost/webpages/home.aspx which became the default page for all website I added to IIS. where can I change that setting not to call that http://localhost/webpages/home.aspx by default.

any pointer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your question correctly.
These steps should help you to produce the result(s) you require:
1 Create your project in VS.
2 Right click Project name.
3 Select Properties.
4 Select Web. 
5 Under Server there is a dropdownbox. Here the default is IIS.
[dropdownbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKBKc.png)

The usual choice as far as I know is between IIS and localhost.
6 Click the Create Virtual Directory button located to the right.
A message box should pop up saying Virtual Directory successfully created!

Here is a link that may be more helpful. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k5RKfOEpOGk&index=9&list=PL6n9fhu94yhXQS_p1i-HLIftB9Y7Vnxlo